# Poor performance when writing large XML-based log file

Tags: python, xml, logging

I'm relatively new to Python, and I've written a fairly simple script logging performance statistics for a defined list of applications. The script samples processes at intervals (using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil)) and returns various stats, which are then logged. To make it easier to do interesting things with the data later, I'm using an XML log format.

Below is a much simplified version of the log structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
    <periodic>
        <sample name="2015-02-25_23-22-54">
            <cpu app="safari">10.5</cpu>
            <memory app="safari">1024</memory>
            <disk app="safari">60</disk>
            <network app="safari">720</network>
        </sample>
    </periodic>
</data>
```

I'm currently using `cElementTree` to parse and create the log file. Each iteration of the sampling loop parses the existing log file, appends the latest data to the end, then writes the new file to disk.

Simplified version of my log writer class:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from xml.dom import minidom

logfile = 'path/to/logfile.xml'

class WriteXmlLog:
    # Parse the logfile.
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = etree.parse(logfile).getroot()
        self.periodic = list(self.root.iter('periodic'))[0]

    def __write_out(self, log_file):
        """Write log contents to file."""
        open(log_file, 'w').write(minidom.parseString(etree.tostring(self.root).replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')).toprettyxml())

    def __create_timestamp(self):
        """Returns a timestamp for naming a process sample iteration."""
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

    def write_sample(self, sample_list):
        """Create or append sample to XML log file."""
        node_sample_time = etree.Element('sample')
        node_sample_time.set('time', self.__create_timestamp())
        for i in sample_list:
            app_dict = i.get('values')
            for a in app_dict:
                sample = etree.Element(a)
                app = str(i.get('appname')).lower()
                sample.set('app', app)
                sample.text = app_dict[a]
                node_sample_time.append(sample)
        self.periodic.append(node_sample_time)
        self.__write_out(logfile)
```

The problem I'm having is that while this script works just fine if the log file is small, it's being used in instances where we have to sample the same processes every few seconds, sometimes for several days running. This can generate log files up to 10 MB (at which point they are rotated) in size. Running the script on a log this size takes about 15 seconds, and pegs 1 CPU core for the whole duration, not to mention excessive memory usage and disk I/O.

`__write_out()` is probably not very efficient since it runs two search and replace operations (to strip extraneous newlines and tabs that mess up `toprettyxml`), then sends the whole output through minidom on every iteration. This is done since `cElementTree` doesn't indent the nodes on its own, making the resulting file less than human-readable. However, the real problem seems to be simply that parsing and writing the entire log every iteration is inherently unscalable.

My first thought was to simply forego using `cElementTree` entirely, "manually" format the results as an XML string, then append them to the end of the log file every iteration (without parsing the existing file at all). The problem with this approach is that the resulting file will not be valid XML since the root node won't have a closing tag. I can have the logger write one when it's finished (it's currently designed to loop infinitely until `SIGTERM`, then do some cleanup on exit) but I would ideally like the log file to always be valid XML during logging. It also just seems clumsy somehow.

**Summary**: What's the best way to write to an XML-based log file with good performance and reasonable resource usage that will scale to a log file size of approximately 10 MB?

Comment: Rewriting the entire log file to append a record seems like an awful idea to me. A log file should be easy to append to. If there a chance to get rid of XML, or to replace one-document log file to a sequence of documents in a file, or a database?

Comment: OP said they're using XML "To make it easier to do interesting things with the data later" -- for which XML is an extremely good choice.  Dropping it because one might have to fiddle with "</data>" at the end would be letting the tail wag the dog. Oh, and JSON has exactly the same issue (just with a final "}" or "]"). Creating many tens of thousands of tiny files introduces other problems including speed (with many file-systems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, you could create each "periodic" element as if it were an entire document (so you could still use cElementTree or similar; or just create it manually as a string).

Then when it's time to write out such a (small) element, open your log file, and seek to the end minus the length of "</data>" (7). Write the new periodic element, then re-write "</data>", and you should be fine.

If you want to be extra careful, after moving to the end, read the last 7 characters to make sure they're as expected, then seek again to position the file before them again.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing, and it works well enough.