# How to append to current XML file? (Login System PHP/XML)

Tags: php, ajax, xml

I've currently made a login system using xml and php. When registering a new user a new xml file gets created. Is there a way i can add the registered users to one xml file instead of creating a new xml every time?

REGISTER.PHP

```
    <?php
    $errors = array();
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/','',$_POST['username']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $c_password = $_POST['confirmPassword'];
    if(file_exists('users/' . $username . '.xml'))
    {
        $errors[] = 'Username already exists';
    }
    //more validation here

    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<user></user>');
        $xml->addChild('password', md5($password));
        $xml->addChild('email', $email);
        $xml->asXML('users/'.$username.'.xml');
        header('Location:login.php');
        die;
    }
}
```

XML FILE:

```
<user>
    <password>827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b</password>
    <email>test@example.com</email>
</user>
```

Comment: Do you need the single file to be valid XML? Because if you just keep appending multiple root nodes to it then it won't be.

Comment: XML isn't really designed to be used as a database. You'd be better off with a real database.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your xml at first

```
<users>
    <user>
        <email></email>
        <password></password>
    </user>
</users>
```

Then simply append new user to users element

Php eg.:

```
<?php

$users = new SimpleXMLElement('<users></users>');
$user = $users->addChild('user');
$user->addChild('email', 'test@test.com');
$user->addChild('password', '1111');

echo $users->asXml();
```

https://3v4l.org/AKdhJ

//edit
And as mentioned above, you should look for some different way for storing users info. MySQL, sqlite, those are much more suitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add user entries in the example you showed, you can just append them to the end of the file, right?

However, @Eakethet is correct that you should add a container (such as "users") around the entries, as a matter of good practice. Without that, there is not single "root", and so it is not a valid XML document (even if you provide a schema, which you haven't yet). Particularly with sensitive and important data, making sure your document is valid is pretty important (you wouldn't ship code with syntax errors in it, data is no less important).

If you add the container, you can't just append to the file any more, because you'd be adding *after* the final end-tag. But you can just backspace over it from the end, write the new entry, and then write a fresh copy of the final end-tag. See the more detailed discussion of this technique at [Poor performance when writing large XML-based log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217911/poor-performance-when-writing-large-xml-based-log-file/30600850#30600850).

But as others have pointed out, user login data seems like it should go in a database, not a text file of any kind. Serial-searching a file for each user as they log in is going to get expensive fairly quickly, unless you know you're only going to have no more than, say, hundreds of users.